# Бот не понимает, что сообщение правильно написано

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, long-poll

Пользователь отправляет сообщение, бот сначала считает, что оно правильное, но сразу после считает его неправильным.

Пользователь: привет

Бот: привет

Бот: я не знаю что значит

Код:

```
    import vk_api, random
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

token = "токен"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token) 
vk._auth_token() #в вк
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 'айди группы') 

print("Бот запущен") 

while True: 
    for event in longpoll.listen(): 

       
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            mess = event.obj['text'] 
            peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']
            
            if mess == "привет": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "да будет с тобой РНБ ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "хай": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "да будет с тобой РНБ  ","random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "хуй": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "Сам ты хуй ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "Хуй": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "Сам ты хуй ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "Привет": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "да будет с тобой РНБ ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "ХУЙ": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "Сам ты хуй ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "Админы": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "Главный Адмэн : Иван                         Редактор Алексей ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "команды": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "⚡️⚡️⚡️КОМАНДЫ                                                                Админы ,                                                    Дети беседы,                                                                        Когда вышел первый мем?", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "Дети беседы":
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "Сын Алексей Т. Родители                                Юлия и                    ‍Ильи    ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "Когда вышел первый мем?":
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "8 мая 9:10 по МСК Иван  выпустил первый мем в группу РНБ Family .Иван спасибо что вы есть", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "Команды": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "⚡️⚡️⚡️КОМАНДЫ                                                                Админы ,                                                    Дети беседы,                                                                        Когда вышел первый мем?", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "Хай": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "да будет с тобой РНБ  ","random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "ХАЙ": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "да будет с тобой РНБ  ","random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            if mess == "ПРИВЕТ": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "да будет с тобой РНБ ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            else:
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": " иди поспи...", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
```

Comment: может с кодировкой проблема?

Comment: код работает без ошибок

Comment: Код != кодировка

Comment: Надо обрамляющий код, тут нормально всё

Comment: В приведенном коде нет фрагмента, который писал бы "я не знаю что значит". В вопросе все на месте? Если это не весь код, то и ответ не весь будет. Отлаживать пробовали пошагово выполнить? Код точняк работает с ошибкой, раз уж невпопад отвечает на действия пользователя:)) Ни один разработчик не может быть уверен в своем коде на 100%, раз уж на то пошло.

Comment: Чтобы в будущем избежать лишних строк, и избежать ошибок из-за капса напиши mess = event.obj['text'].lower(), чтобы все символы сообщения были в нижнем регистре, как раз возможно вы написали Привет, вместо привет

Answer (score 0):

После первого if замените остальные if на elif и ваша проблема решена

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/517279)

Comment: Как раз-ьаки является, ведь у него начальное if исполняется, а остальные нет, в итоге срабатывает else

Comment: В итоге бот даёт два ответа

Comment: и в самом деле является, но как-то неразвернуто и его сложно воспринять... хотя автор либо не умеет делать правки в вопросах либо что... запостил новый вопрос с дополнением не принимая никаких когнитивных усилий... дичь.